# Design pattern: C++ Abstraction Layer

Tags: c++, c, abstraction, hal

I'm trying to write an abstraction layer to let my code run on different platforms. Let me give an example for two classes that I ultimately want to use in the high level code:

```
class Thread
{
public:
    Thread();
    virtual ~Thread();

    void start();
    void stop();

    virtual void callback() = 0;
};

class Display 
{
public:
    static void drawText(const char* text);
};
```

My trouble is: What design pattern can I use to let low-level code fill in the implementation? 
Here are my thoughs and why I don't think they are a good solution:

1. In theory there's no problem in having the above definition sit in `highLevel/thread.h` and the platform specific implementation sit in `lowLevel/platformA/thread.cpp`. This is a low-overhead solution that is resolved at link-time. The only problem is that the low level implementation can't add any member variables or member functions to it. This makes certain things impossible to implement.
2. A way out would be to add this to the definition (basically the Pimpl-Idiom):

   ```
   class Thread 
   { 
       // ...
   private:
       void* impl_data;
   }
   ```

   Now the low level code can have it's own struct or objects stored in the void pointer. The trouble here is that its ugly to read and painful to program.
3. I could make `class Thread` pure virtual and implement the low level functionality by inheriting from it. The high level code could access the low level implementation by calling a factory function like this:

   ```
   // thread.h, below the pure virtual class definition 
   extern "C" void* makeNewThread();

   // in lowlevel/platformA/thread.h 
   class ThreadImpl: public Thread
   { ... };

   // in lowLevel/platformA/thread.cpp
   extern "C" void* makeNewThread() { return new ThreadImpl(); }
   ```

   This would be tidy enough but it fails for static classes. My abstraction layer will be used for hardware and IO things and I would really like to be able to have `Display::drawText(...)` instead of carrying around pointers to a single `Display` class.
4. Another option is to use only C-style functions that can be resolved at link time like this `extern "C" handle_t createThread()`. This is easy and great for accessing low level hardware that is there only once (like a display). But for anything that can be there multiple times (locks, threads, memory management) I have to carry around handles in my high level code which is ugly or have a high level wrapper class that hides the handles. Either way I have the overhead of having to associate the handles with the respective functionality on both the high level and the low level side.
5. My last thought is a hybrid structure. Pure C-style `extern "C"` functions for low level stuff that is there only once. Factory functions (see 3.) for stuff that can be there multiple times. But I fear that something hybrid will lead to inconsistent, unreadable code.

I'd be very grateful for hints to design patterns that fit my requirements.

Comment: Didn't read your whole question yet. But C++ has an abstraction layer for threads since c++11.

Comment: I'm working on an embedded target with FreeRTOS suppying the threading stuff. Another platform is a computer based emulation for easier development of the high level code. I don't think C++11 supports this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want value semantics for your `Thread` class and wonder where to add the indirection to make it portable. So you use the pimpl idiom, and some conditional compilation.
Depending on where you want the complexity of your build tool to be, and if you want to keep all the low level code as self contained as possible, You do the following:

In you high level header `Thread.hpp`, you define:

```
class Thread
{
  class Impl:
  Impl *pimpl; // or better yet, some smart pointer
public:
  Thread ();
  ~Thread();
  // Other stuff;
};
```

Than, in your thread sources directory, you define files along this fashion:

`Thread_PlatformA.cpp`

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_A

#include <Thread.hpp>

Thread::Thread()
{
  // Platform A specific code goes here, initialize the pimpl;
}

Thread::~Thread()
{
  // Platform A specific code goes here, release the pimpl;
}

#endif
```

Building `Thread.o` becomes a simple matter of taking all `Thread_*.cpp` files in the Thread directory, and having your build system come up with the correct `-D` option to the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the Pimpl idiom before. It basically is 2. of my initial post. I have seriously considered to do this, but I find that the code becomes really ugly.

Comment: @LoveDaOOP, if you use `void*` sure. If you don't circumvent the type system, than not so much.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer now, because it seems to be the most tidy solution. In my project I ultimately went for a plain C-style interface (4. in my initial post). On the high-level side I have wrapper classes that hide all the handles. By defining a handle as `typedef void* threadHandle_t` I can have my low level code use the handle as whatever seems suitable. Often the handle will be abused to be a pointer to an object in the low level code. That way I don't have to use tables or maps to associate the handles with their respective objects on the low level side. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a platform-agnostic base class, because your code is only compiled for a single concrete platform at a time.

Just set the include path to, for example, `-Iinclude/generic -Iinclude/platform`, and have a separate Thread class in each supported *platform*'s include directory.

You can (and should) write platform-agnostic tests, compiled & executed by default, which confirm your different platform-specific implementations adhere to the same interface and semantics.

PS. As StoryTeller says, Thread is a bad example since there's already a portable `std::thread`. I'm assuming there's some other platform-specific detail you really do need to abstract.

PPS. You still need to figure out the correct split between *generic* (platform-agnostic) code and platform-specific code: there's no magic bullet for deciding what goes where, just a series of tradeoffs between reuse/duplication, simple versus highly-parameterized code, etc.

Comment: Surely not a separate `Thread` class, but separate *implementations* of the `Thread` class. And I don't follow with the include path, since these are source directories :)

Comment: If I write two different classes (both called `Thread`) in different directories, expose the same public interface from each but implement them differently, and ensure _only one_ can be included in a given translation unit & whole program ... are they different classes? Different implementations of the same class? It's a distinction without a useful difference.

Comment: ODR says there's only one such class in the system. And it's defined in the high level header. The implementation may vary. And being precise on semantics can help the OP figure out what they need to do.

Comment: Setting your include path (and lib path, if it's not a header-only library) satisfies ODR. You're either building (say) a PlatformX binary, out of the platform-agnostic code plus the PlatformX-specific code, or you're building a PlatformY binary out of the platform-agnostic code plus the PlatformY-specific code. You have One Definition of anything platform-specific - but which is left up to the build system

Comment: My problem is: If I let the platform specific implementation supply both `thread.h`and `thread.cpp` then essentially the platform specific code defines the interface. I don't like that. The interface really should be defined by the high level code. It juste seems hacky and messy to ignore the "natural" hierarchy. If I let `thread.h` sit in the high level code and have a matching `thread.cpp` in each platforms code, then my platform specific implementations can't add member variables oder inheritance etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious, what would it be like to design this situation like the following (just sticking to the thread):

```
// Your generic include level:
// thread.h
class Thread : public 
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
    PlatformAThread
#elif PLATFORM_B
    PlatformBThread
// any more stuff you need in here
#endif
{  
    Thread();
    virtual ~Thread();

    void start();
    void stop();

    virtual void callback() = 0;
} ;
```

which does not contain anything about implementation, just the interface

Then you have:

```
// platformA directory 
class PlatformAThread { ... };
```

and this will automatically result that when you create your "generic" `Thread` object you automatically get also a platform dependent class which automatically sets up its internals, and which might have platform specific operations, and certainly your `PlatformAThread` class might derive from a generic `Base` class having common things you might need.

You will also need to set up your build system to automatically recognize the platform specific directories.

Also, please note, that I have the tendency to create hierarchies of class inheritances, and some people advise against this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: That is a nice idea. But it assumes that the high level code knows what platform it will be run on. I could use macros with stringyfication to supply the right class name via the makefiles. Like this:

    `class Thread: public TREAD_IMPL`

Then in the build settings I could add the right preprocessor definitions. Buts that also is kind of messy.